# continuity and differentiability check

Tags: real-analysis

A function y=f(x) is defined para-metrically as y=t^2+t|t|,x=2t-|t|, t is in R. Then at x=0, f(x) is 
(A) continuous but not differentiable
(B)  differentiable
(C) discontinuous
(D) none of the above

Answer (score 0):

If we consider the cases that either t is positive or negative, if t is positive y=2t^2, x=t, that is y=2x^2, obviously differentiable,
when t is negative, y=0,x=3t, that means y=0, which is also differentiable.

Comment: please tell me is it right or not?